# android xml: reference a menu in multiple places.

Tags: android, xml, contextmenu

I have:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/fp_pitcher"
    android:title="Pitcher">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/caught"
            android:title="Caught">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/not_caught"
            android:title="Not Caught">
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/fp_catcher"
    android:title="Catcher">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@id/caught"
            android:title="Caught">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@id/not_caught"
            android:title="Not Caught">
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/fp_firstbaseman"
    android:title="First Baseman">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/caught"
            android:title="Caught">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/not_caught"
            android:title="Not Caught">
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
<!--SNIP, continues for every fielding position. -->
```

So you see this inner menu is the same for each of the outer items. 
Is there a way I can reference the same menu over and over again?
This would save me time later, if I needed to modify the inner menu.

Comment: You can refer this menu at multiple places by inflating the layout by MenuInflater.

Comment: @AkashG - Do you mean using the MenuInflater in onContextItemSelected? 
If so - how do I reference the menu to pass into inflate?